# @ManyToMany with extra column - how to load via Spring Data?

Tags: spring, hibernate, many-to-many, spring-data-jpa

I have many to many relation between User and Event. I need to have extra column in relational table. I did id:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
    private Set<EventUser> eventUsers = new HashSet<>();

//

}

@Entity
public class Event {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="event")
    private Set<EventUser> eventUsers = new HashSet<>();

//

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Event_User")
public class EventUser  {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String reaction;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "event_id")
    private Event event;

//

}
```

But now... I don't know how to load all events where user has concrete email. Before it I used method:
findByUsersEmail(String email);

Now I can't do this, because Event doesn't have Set users field.

Any ideas ?

Comment: 1. Change structure of tables: User, Event, Reaction, user-event-reaction
2. Change query at `findByEmail`-method
3. What about `@JoinTable` if you need only events and don't need reasons

Answer (score 1):

What you need here is [property-expressions](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions).

Just a quick idea to start:

```
findByEventUsers_UserEmail(String email);
```

**Note:** Dont forget that creating queries by method names is a very limited approach and only used by trivial cases. In any other case, don't be afraid of using the `@Query` annotation on the method or write JPQL/Criteria API manually.